# Mongo Service running but command line functionalities are not working

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am new to mongo. I am following pluralsight's course to mongo's introduction.

I have installed mongo as a service using command

```
C:\Windows\system32>"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongod.exe" --config "C:/mongod.conf" --install
```

Config file consists of  :

```
dbpath= C:/pluralsight/db

logpath=C:/pluralsight/mongo-server.log

verbose=vvvvv
```

Then I started the service using

```
net start mongodb
```

Inspit eof the service running on my machine, i am not able to run the mongo shell on my system. The course on pluralsight shows the tutor running the shell after the installation, but i am not able to do it. Any reasons why?

[image: Screenshot of my cmd]

Comment: you can try to add the mongodb location to the path variable and then execute it.

Comment: @talentedandrew I tried to add it to path variable using setx path "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\" but it is still not working for me

Comment: considering that your path is correct,have you tried running as an administrator?

Comment: It says "SUCCESS: Specified value was saved."

Comment: your mongodb server is also not running? "command > mongod"

Answer (score 2):

Try `"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongo.exe"` instead of just `mongo`. It doesn't seem to be in your path. If you would like to add it to your path, you can checkout this question [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml).

Comment: I tried to add it to path variable using setx path "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\" but it is still not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Form the screenshot it looks like mongo is not in your path.
try executing "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongo.exe"